# Matlab Array Division

Tags: arrays, matlab, division

I have been playing with matlab and was trying to calculate absolute relative error using two arrays. However, when I divide the two arrays, my resulting array has the same value throughout the array even though when I calculate the values by hand, they are not all the same. I was wondering why my resulting array shows the same answer for every value in the array.

Here is my code:

```matlab
function [X] = absrelerror(A, B)

% Calculates absolute relative error for true value A and approximate value B.

A = linspace(sin(-pi/6), sin(pi/6), 50); %True
B = linspace(-pi/6, pi/6, 50); %Approximate

Y = abs((A-B) ./ A); %ARE equation
X = Y * 100; %convert to percent


end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have approached the problem in a wrong way.

Here, the first elements of both `A` and `B` are constant. Also, the spacing between two elements of any of the vectors is also constant. Say, they are `c` and `d` where `c = {A(50) - A(1)}/49` and `d = {B(50) - B(1)}/49`. Now, the nth value of `Y` is  `{A(1)*nc - B(1)*nd}/{A(1)*c} = {A(1)*c - B(1)*c}/A(1)` which is constant. So, it's not surprising that MATLAB is giving a constant value in `Y`.

If I have understood correctly what you are trying to do, then you should do it in the following way:

```matlab
%A = linspace(sin(-pi/6), sin(pi/6), 50); %True
B = linspace(-pi/6, pi/6, 50); %Approximate

%Y = abs((A-B) ./ A); %ARE equation
%X = Y * 100; %convert to percent

A = sin(B);
X = abs((A-B)./A) * 100;

fprintf('%f ', X)
```

The output is:
`4.719755 4.330958 3.960262 3.607413 3.272170 2.954306 2.653606 2.369868 2.102903 1.852533 1.618593 1.400927 1.199394 1.013862 0.844209 0.690325 0.552111 0.429477 0.322344 0.230643 0.154315 0.093311 0.047592 0.017130 0.001903 0.001903 0.017130 0.047592 0.093311 0.154315 0.230643 0.322344 0.429477 0.552111 0.690325 0.844209 1.013862 1.199394 1.400927 1.618593 1.852533 2.102903 2.369868 2.653606 2.954306 3.272170 3.607413 3.960262 4.330958 4.719755`